# Random Number Generator Generates Same Numbers on Android

Tags: java, android, random, libgdx

I have recently started learning about programming mobile applications. 
I was doing some practice, writing basic programs. 
First of all I am using LibGDX, so first I test my application on desktop then test it on android.

Somewhere in my program it has to generate 3 random numbers from 0, 1, 2 ( they can be the same numbers as long as they are random ). On desktop my program works fine, it generates 3 random numbers each time i run it. However when i try it on my android phone, all the three numbers are the same.
For example 3 trials:
My desktop: 0-0-1, 2-1-2, 2-0-1
My phone; 0-0-0, 2-2-2, 0-0-0;

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
  postNumber(randomNumber);//This function I wrote sends the randomNumber to be drawn on the screen

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should initialize the `Random()` instance *outside* your loop - or ideally, just once. (The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html) states that it's thread-safe, so you shouldn't need one per thread or anything like that.)

Basically, it's seeding a new instance of `Random` based on the current time... and that current time isn't changing significantly between iterations of the loop. This is a common error, and the Oracle Java implementation fixed it a while ago - it looks like the Android implementation hasn't, yet. But fundamentally it's a problem of your own making, and definitely avoidable by using a single instance of `Random` to generate all your numbers.